# Does any thermal fuse with the same cut off temperature work?

Tags: fuses, thermal

Would any thermal fuse cutoff for 216°C work as a replacement for the fuse in the picture below?

[image: Fuse picture]

Comment: Alright, so I bought this http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0087ZRIAA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1, I just replaced it with the one that melted in my portable electric burner. Is there any other risk that may happen if I ONLY replaced the thermal fuse? I don't want my grandpa to use a device that may or may not explode. Also, the burner has a metal housing, so I'm not worried about it melting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any similar 216°C thermal fuse with a 10A or better current rating and an appropriate voltage rating should be fine.

[image]

For example, a [CANTHERM](http://www.cantherm.com/media/productPDF/SDF_FEB_2013.pdf) SDF DF216S, which is approved for use at 250V 10A or 15A depending on the safety agency.

[image]

If it's held in a clip or something like that, make sure the diameter is close enough that it will behave similarly thermally.

Comment: Is there a difference between "X3" and "R3"? Also, it's held by a screw terminal.

Comment: The diameter of the clip? That last note is unclear, at least to me. Do you mean that if the fuse is held in a clip to make sure the thermal characteristics are similar between fuse and clip? Or that the clip is tightly holding the fuse maybe?

Comment: X3 and R3- probably there is, and probably unique to that Chinese maker. Could be lead length, finish or something else.

Comment: @sherrellbc Yes, if it's held by a clip to a heatsink or a housing and you get a replacement that's too loose to follow the temperature or too tight to fit, it isn't going to do the job.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had the wrong impression of what this device was. So, the fuse heats up as your device heats and will interrupt current flow if too hot. I was thinking it was just a fuse that heated if too much current passed through it, so it did not make much sense to couple it to the system and potentially introduce more heat. Do these fuses have internal hysteresis? Otherwise it would seem like they would cycle on/off as they heated and cooled around their cut-ff temperature.

Comment: @sherrellbc they have a lot of hysteresis -- they shut off once and never come on again! They're a safety device to prevent fires- if a panini press overheats or the air to a hair dryer is blocked they'll shut down permanently before anything bad happens. That's why they should be replaced with a very similar device.